# Как сделать переключение языков с правильным редиректом (WordPress Multisite)?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, редирект, wordpress-multisite, смена-языка

Есть сайт на Wordpress multisite. Стоят три языковых сайто-версии на подкаталогах:

1. мойсайт.ru (сайт на русском, основной)
2. мойсайт.ru/en/ (версия на
   англ.яз)
3. мойсайт.ru/de/ (версия на нем.яз)

Сейчас, если я нахожусь на, допустим, мойсайт.ru/блог/ и кликну по ссылке перехода на англ.версию (стоит сейчас обычная ссылка вида `<a href="/en">EN</a>`), то окажусь на главной странице мойсайт.ru/en/, а не на мойсайт.ru/en/блог/, как хотелось бы.

**Как сделать, чтобы при переключении языка пользователь оставался на той же странице, с которой произошло переключение языка?** Не соображу, как ссылки оформить правильно; подозреваю, что можно решить через .htaccess.

Comment: Зачем делать мультисайт для разных языков? Не проще ли использовать polylang или wpml для этого?

Comment: Предполагается разный контент для языковых версий просто

Comment: И что мешает пихать разный контент через упомянутые выше плагины? В мультисайте у вас не будет нормальных связей между постами, что не есть хорошо

Comment: Даже не знаю. Я думал, что языковые плагины для этого не подходят. Все таки под мои нужды мне казалось, что ближе мультисайт...

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте при выводе ссылок на другие языки [$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.server.php). Пример: Используйте так же функцию [get_home_url()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_home_url). Первым параметром в которой необходимо указать ID сайта среди мультисайтов.

```php
<a href="<?= get_home_url( 1, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ); ?>">RU</a>
<a href="<?= get_home_url( 2, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ); ?>">EN</a>
<a href="<?= get_home_url( 3, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ); ?>">DE</a>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Сейчас попробую